# Creation of an Object that is inside of another object

Tags: java, architecture, text-based

I want to keep as many things in separate java files for code readability and for debugging issues.

I have a java class Called **Actor**. The Actor class is designed to be an object that holds all the players information, but also be used for other things, like monsters, ect.

Another class called **Status**.
This class takes care of all the status ailments and will modify the attributes to the Actor (Example: if they are stunned).

I want this Status Class to be a part of Actor, without nesting the classes. Is this possible?

Comment: The term to look for is [composition](http://www.journaldev.com/1325/what-is-composition-in-java-java-composition-example) - two classes interact with each other but don't extend from each other.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading up on Java programming, and starting with more basic aspects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `Status` in one file

```
class Status {
}
```

And your `Actor` in another file, all you have to do is have an instance of the `Status` object inside your `Actor` class

```
class Actor {
    Status myStatus = new Status();

    public Actor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the `Actor` a member of type `Status`:

```
class Status {
  ...
}

class Actor {
  Status status;
}
```

You can either have the `Actor` construct the status object directly in its own constructor, or receive a `Status` instance as a parameter to the constructor.